# Distribution of $X^2+Y^2$ where $X,Y$ are independent $U[0,1]$ variables

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables which are uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1]$. Find the density of the random variable $Z = X^{2} + Y^{2}$.

Should I compute the density of $X^{2}$ and $Y^{2}$ first? And how to solve it?

Comment: Hint: Compute $\mathbb P(X^2 + Y^2 \le z)$ using geometry.

Comment: I have tried that it is a circle, but I encoutered some computation problems, I don't know how to use the geometry property.

Comment: You want the area of the intersection of the disk $x^2 + y^2 \le z$  with the unit square $0 \le x,y \le 1$.  There are two cases to consider: $0 \le z\le 1$ where you have a quarter-disk, and $1 \le z \le 2$ where you have two triangles and a sector.

Comment: I know the case $0 \leq z \leq 1$ now. How can I compute the case $1 \leq z \leq 2$,  and what are two triangles and a sector?

Comment: I'll put it in an answer so I can include a picture.

Answer (score 1):

For $1 \le z \le 2$, the region $x^2 + y^2 \le z$, $0 \le x,y \le 1$ looks like this:

[image]

The two right triangles have height $\sqrt{z-1}$ and base $1$, so total area $\sqrt{z-1}$.  The sector  has opening angle $\pi/2 - 2 \arctan(\sqrt{z-1})$ and radius $\sqrt{z}$, so
area $(\pi/2 - 2 \arctan(\sqrt{z-1})) z/2$.  Thus
$$ \mathbb P(X^2 + Y^2 \le z) = \sqrt{z-1} + (\pi/2 - 2 \arctan(\sqrt{z-1})) z/2$$
The density of $X^2 + Y^2$ in this interval is the derivative of that, or
$$ \pi/4 - \arctan(\sqrt{z-1})$$